# Are GET variables used in Google's search engine?

Tags: search-engine

Say i have a site with movies. Now each movie doesn't have each own page, but passing the id or the name of the movie to one specific page, i.e movies.php, the data from the database are loaded in that page..
Now if i search in google a specific movie will my site be listed with that movie in the results??
In other words, if i have that movie stored in my database, but don't have an individual page for it, will it appear in search engines just by getting the GET variable, i.e $movie_name, passed in the movies.php??

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and as such it's not on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your movies has its own page, i.e. `movies.com/movies.php?movie=half_baked`
then that will count as a unique page.

You need to give Google a way of differentiating between different pages.

you can search google for your website by typing `site:yoursite.com`. That will show you each page google has indexed.

look into canonical pages http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: So long story sort, every GET variable i pass to a page counts as an individual page??  
And if a search in google, for example lord of the rings, it will bring up as a result movies.com/movies.php?movie=lord_of_the_rings??

Comment: short answer:yes. Make sure each page has different content. set up an account on google.com/webmaster. learn about canonical links. and for god's sake, `USE GOOGLE`. It's amazing what can be learned if you read.

Comment: ok..thank you!  
i will read about canonical links!!